# Python says array dimensions aren't matching, but I don't see why not

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on code for a generic algorithm, and am looking to perform a crossover on the current population, but do not see why the function's array dimensions aren't matching.

I've tried print-line debugging to see if the array dimensions are changing, but I don't see how...

## The crossover code:

```
def crossover(self,parent, pop):
    if np.random.rand() < self.CROSS_RATE: # Ensures crossover happens at crossover rate
        i_ = np.random.randint(0, self.POP_SIZE) # Select another individual from pop
        cross_points = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=self.DNA_SIZE).astype(np.bool) # Choose crossover points
        parent[cross_points] = pop[i_,cross_points] # Mating and produce one child
    return parent
```

## The code calling the function:

```
pop = np.random.randint(2, size=(100,arr.shape[1] - 1)) # initialze initial population

ga = Genetic_Algorithm(arr, DNA_SIZE = arr.shape[1] - 1)

for i in range(0,ga.N_GENERATIONS):
    pop = ga.mutate(pop)
    pop_copy = pop.copy()
    for j in range(0,pop.shape[0]):
        np.vstack([pop,ga.crossover(pop[j,:],pop_copy)])
    calculated_results = ga.translateDNA(pop)
    fitness = ga.get_fitness_one(calculated_results,ga.output_data)
    print("Most fit model:",pop[np.argmax(fitness),:])

    pop = ga.select(pop,fitness)
```

Comment: Could you post details from the error message you are getting? It would be helpful at least to know the line number that is causing the error. Also consider replacing random numbers with constants when debugging semantic errors like array size and index problems, it can make things much simpler.

Comment: Where's the error message? It should be in your question as well.